# How to work with .net 6 web api , where shared business logic across multiple apis/contorllers?

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, web-development-server

I am beginner in Web Development. I need a help designing .net 6 web api project.

I have web application , which has front end with HTML-JS-CSS and back end with .net 6 web api.

I have set of services

1. login API
2. Pre_Processing Api
3. Transfer API

I have added session in project.

front end calls "pre_processing api", after which it return large set of objects to front end. For each such object the third "transfer api" is been called.

I have injected dbcontext using entity framework.

****Now I need to add credit mechanism for allowing and disallowing
transferring activity**** which is based on platform basis (having multiple users on one system).

The business logic is shared in "pre_processing" and "transfer api".
I need to lock/deduct a credit value from database table for user , on how many transfers he is going to make in advance. which should reflect to other user.

If I lock/deduct credit in database table in pre_processing(controller) api.
I need to rollback the locking of credits [the action of pre_processing api] on results(success /failure) of "transfer api".

storing everything information in session variable is making logic complex and inaccurate.

**How could i go further?**

**I am not able to inject a dbcontext per user session?**.
**Is there any library one can use to implement credit based transactions?****

I tried with storing transaction information in session.
The dbcontext now disposes with each http request.
But i am expecting more robust and consistent approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.